# Is there any advantage Bit manipulation have here?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
    # include<bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std; 
 
long multiplyBySeven(long n)  
{    
    return ((n<<3) - n);  
}  
    
int main()  
{  
    long n = 4;  
      
    cout<<multiplyBySeven(n);  
    
    return 0;  
}
```

Does the above approach have any advantage over the conventional one?

Comment: That approach has been used on CPUs that cannot multiply.  If you are writing C++, you _can_ multiply.  And you would only benefit from that approach if you wanted your code to be difficult to read.

Comment: If there is an advantage on any particular target platform, the compiler probably knows about it and does the same. You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3x5vv4) that all the major compilers compile the obvious code to the same code as that.

Comment: Not any more. Compilers already know about these tricks.

Comment: In general, you should leave these kinds of tricks to your compiler when you enable optimizations. Your compiler for the most part is way smarter than you at these kinds of things. If you want want to multiply by seven, just write `n * 7` and move on.

Comment: It should be said that not all compilers are as smart as the ones that modern desktop c++ developers use. Some embedded compilers will do the bare minimum and tricks like this are still of value to the programmer.

Comment: Signed shift left of a negative number is undefined, before C++20.

Comment: @JoePerri Do you know of concrete examples of currently shipping compilers that do not know how to optimize an integer multiplication by a constant on platforms without a hardware multiplier? When I last programmed embedded systems in the early 2000s, the various compilers I used (for PowerPC, ARM, SH4) already implemented an extensive number of optimizations, and it stands to reason that they have improved in the past 15 years.

Comment: @njuffa Ancient altera fpgas using the NIOS core would only reduce powers of 2 directly and not do anything more fancy than that. PIC compilers were also dicey in this regard.

Comment: @JoePerri Approximately how long ago in the past are we talking about? The present asker is looking for advice based on the situation as it is now.

Comment: @njuffa I was using that PIC compiler last year. Legacy is a concern and will always be for embedded applications. Using a shiny cortex-m with gcc support will be fine but that luxury may not always be there.

Comment: @JoePerri Point taken. That's good to know about PIC; thanks for pointing it out. So a reasonable recommendation might be to write C++ code in a natural way, but to check the generated assembly code (or the disassembled generated machine code) where performance is critical, and use less readable bit-twiddling constructs only where necessary.